# Numpy Detection of region borders

Tags: python, numpy

Given a 1 dimensional array of Values:

A = [x,..,x,0,..,0,x,..,x,0,..,0,x,..,x,........]

where:

x,..,x  stands for for an arbitrary number of arbitrary Values

and

0,..,0  stands for an arbitrary number of Zeros

I need to find a fast algorithm to find the indices of the borders 
 i.e.: ..,x,0,.. and ..,0,x..

This problem seems to lend itself to parallelization but that is beyond my experience simple looping over the array is to slow as the data is to big

THX
Martin

Comment: What did you try so far? what errors are you getting?

Comment: How big is your array? Are there many more zeros than xs, more xs than zeros or about the same amount of both? Are there a large number of these borders (relative to the size) or a small number?

Comment: @RubenBermudez No errors, just to long a calculation

Comment: @chthonicdaemon Length ~ 200 000 Values. The junks of Zeros have a known max length <= ~ 5000 Values --- relative small Number of borders

Comment: Can you give an example of `A` as runnable Python code? For example `A = np.array([1, 2, 3])` and an example of the output you expect for that `A`? The answer will probably involve `np.diff` or `np.ediff1d`.

Comment: At http://s54.photobucket.com/user/martburg/media/Zeros_zpscd400abb.png.html?sort=3&o=0 there is a matplotlib plot of a set of Data

Comment: @martburg please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @MrE just learning my way arround stackoverflow

Comment: On a bit of a random note, this problem actually doesn't lend itself to parallelization at all. The bottleneck is going to be memory access, not CPU speed. There are next to no calculations to preform, but there is a large array to go through.  If you're careful about it, you should be able to get a speedup with a parallel approach, but it's not going to be as simple as you might think at first glance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@chthonicdaemon's answer gets you 90% of the way there, but if you actually want to use the indices to chop up your array, you need some additional information.

Presumably, you want to use the indicies to extract the regions of the array that aren't 0. You've found the indices where the array changes, but you don't know if the change was from `True` to `False` or the opposite way around. Therefore, you need to check the first and last values and adjust accordingly. Otherwise, you'll wind up extracting the segment of zeros instead of data in some cases.

For example:

```
import numpy as np

def contiguous_regions(condition):
    """Finds contiguous True regions of the 1D boolean array "condition".
    Returns a 2D array where the first column is the start index of the region
    and the second column is the end index."""
    # Find the indicies of changes in "condition"
    idx = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(condition)) + 1

    # Prepend or append the start or end indicies to "idx"
    # if there's a block of "True"'s at the start or end...
    if condition[0]:
        idx = np.append(0, idx)
    if condition[-1]:
        idx = np.append(idx, len(condition))

    return idx.reshape(-1, 2)

# Generate an example dataset...
t = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 20)
x = np.abs(np.sin(t)) + 0.1
x[np.sin(t) < 0.5] = 0

print x

# Get the contiguous regions where x is not 0
for start, stop in contiguous_regions(x != 0):
    print x[start:stop]
```

So in this case, our example dataset looks like:

```
array([ 0.        ,  0.71421271,  1.06940027,  1.01577333,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.93716648,  1.09658449,  0.83572391,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ])
```

And by doing:

```
for start, stop in contiguous_regions(x != 0):
    print x[start:stop]
```

We'll get:

```
[ 0.71421271  1.06940027  1.01577333]
[ 0.93716648  1.09658449  0.83572391]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should at least push the looping down into the Numpy primitives, although it will traverse the array three times:

```
A = 2*(rand(200000)>0.2)  # testing data
borders = flatnonzero(diff(A==0))
```

This takes 1.79 ms on my computer.

Comment: Works with my test Data -- I have to digest what's happening in that pice of code

Comment: +1, but there's actually a subtle bug with what you're currently doing. If the OP's array starts or ends with a chunk of zeros, you're going to need to prepend/append 0/-1 to `borders`.  Of course, the OP did just ask for the indicies of the changes, which this accomplishes. To actually use the result, though, you need to know which direction the change is in.